# AppDomainSetup usage in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, appdomain, appdomainsetup

Since *SetShadowCopyPath* and *SetShadowCopyFiles* became obsolete since .NET 2.0, I want to set up these params via *ShadowCopyDirectories* and *ShadowCopyFiles* properties from **AppDomainSetup** class.

In MSDN stands that this is the proper usage:

```
AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
ads.ShadowCopyDirectories = .. semicolon separated paths ...
ads.ShadowCopyFiles = ... true/false ...
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyAppDomain", null, ads);
```

which is fine. But how do I make this work on current domain of my running web application since it's **AppDomain** is created by ASP.NET on application initialization (when first user request comes to IIS) and I'm unable to change current domain setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow copying is enabled by default on ASP.NET applications. Check the [hostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228159%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) element.

You should also read the section on [shadow copying](http://books.google.gr/books?id=SwWw44nYJNgC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA11) in Essential ASP.NET With Examples in C# by Fritz Onion.